# PDF Import into SQL

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a pdf file that I converted to seperate HTML files, 
My goal is to import them into MS SQL so I can search the table for specific identifiers and
display the result on a webpage.

I am able to read all the html files, and get it into the SQL table, but complete sentences are being cut of by the converter because they are splitted into multiple div containers.

```
<div class="S2"> DA0-17.0</div>
<div class="S5"> 1416</div>
<div class="S2"> Required when the subscriber is the same person as the patient. If</div>
<div class="S5"> 2698</div>
<div class="S2"> the subscriber is not the same person as the patient, do not use</div>
<div class="S2"> this element.</div>
<div class="S4"> CODE</div>
<div class="S4"> DEFINITION</div>
<div class="S2"> 18</div>
<div class="S2"> Self</div>
```

I am trying to retrieve class S2.

I don't need class S5 or S4
Attached is a sample of the SQL results,
The insert string is dynamicly created depending on how many fields there are needed.

[image: SQL Results]

Below is the part the creates the insert values:

```
If iFieldNum = 1 Then
    sInsertstring = sInsertstring + "id2, " + "num" + CStr(iFieldNum)
    sInsertValues = sInsertValues + "'" + msbr + "', '" + ms2 + "'"
Else
    sInsertstring = sInsertstring + ", num" + CStr(iFieldNum)
    sInsertValues = sInsertValues + ", '" + ms2 + "'"
End If
iFieldNum += 1
```

Hopefully someone can assist me with this problem or point me in the right direction on how to fix this issue.
Complete code is available upon request.
Thanks for your time,
Robert.

Ps: This is application based, not web

In reply to Edper:

```
Dim fFileName As String
Dim dListing As New DirectoryInfo(My.Settings.ImportDir)
Dim aFileArray As FileInfo() = dListing.GetFiles()
Dim fFiles As FileInfo
    For Each fFiles In aFileArray
    fFileName = fFiles.Name
    Dim fStream = New FileStream(My.Settings.ImportDir + "\" + fFileName, FileMode.Open)
    Dim sReader = New StreamReader(fStream)
```

In reply to Edper.
What I want is the following:

In the HTML files (around 700) are div containers with different class names.

```
 <div class="S2"> Required when the subscriber is the same person as the patient. If</div>
 <div class="S5"> 2698</div>
 <div class="S2"> the subscriber is not the same person as the patient, do not use</div>
 <div class="S2"> this element.</div>
```

I am able to create insert statements for each occurrence, however I want the "Description" between the `<div class="S5">` and `<div class="S4">` to be one long line of text, at the moment it is split up in 3 parts which I don't want, I don't know how to combine them.
My knowledge of VB.NET is fairly limited, and I am trying to learn as I go along, I was pro-efficient in classic ASP but that won't work in this case.

I'm sorry for the bad formulation of my question..
I simply don't know how else to explain it further..

Comment: Do you want div of the same class as one sentence and then insert it to your table? Are you using Webbrowser control on this one?

Comment: @Edper, I updated my question with a part of the code.
And yes, I would like it to be 1 sentence instead of multiple parts.

Comment: So, let me clarify again. You have converted PDF files into HTML files. But your problem is you have classes that are into multiple divs? And you want to get those multiple divs (one class) into one sentence to be added then to your database table? I am not really sure what you are trying to accomplished here so kindly be more specific on your question and target the area you want others to focus on in order we can help you. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I did not see the last portion of your reply which basically answers my question. So, you have an HTML file I presume so why not load on a webbrowser that is not visible to the user but one you could work on from behind. Because from a webbrowser it is more easier to get the classes (although ID is ideal) than from a stream for example.

Comment: @Edper Is there a way for me to send you a private message?

Comment: If not, here is a bigger part of the code, it's not pretty maybe, but well, let me know when you seen it so I can delete it. http://pastebin.com/aaArCwX4

Comment: There is no consistent pattern in your example so it would be wise if you give a concrete example of the possible output that you want. And how could we detect patters in that case we could construct the possible logic of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably drop a `Webbrowser` control in your form and then just make it `visible = false` so as not to show it. Then just declare a global variable for string builder like:

```
Dim builder As New StringBuilder
```

Then when you get all the HTML files in this code and you could probably do like this:

```
Dim fFileName As String
Dim dListing As New DirectoryInfo(My.Settings.ImportDir)
Dim aFileArray As FileInfo() = dListing.GetFiles()
Dim fFiles As FileInfo

For Each fFiles In aFileArray
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(dListing&"\"&fFiles)
Next
```

And when the html is loaded completely using the `WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted` event you then get all the classes (like `S2`) from the multiple `divs` like:

```
    Dim elems As HtmlElementCollection
    elems = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("DIV")

    For Each elem As HtmlElement In elems

        If (elem.GetAttribute("className") = "S2") Then
            builder.Append(elem.InnerHtml).Append(" ")
        End If
    Next

    'Do something for string builder (i.e. builder.ToString()) here before clearing the String Builder like this could be where you insert the records to your table probably

    builder.Clear()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer Edper, I am however about to go home, so I will try this suggestion tomorrow, and I will accept it then :)
Thanks!

Comment: I got another question for you though, I end up with the same string I get now, how is this approach any different?

Comment: In my case I put all the class S2 into one string and not separate ones. Is that how it came out for you also? Because you were saying in your original post that you want it in one sentence instead of multiple parts. Or i misunderstood completely your problem :-)

Comment: I meant to say: I am getting all the S2's in one string, and am able to input it into the DB, the problem is however that the "Description" is broken up into multiple parts, I want it to be 1 part, is it possible to scan for S5 and S4 and get the lines in between those 2?

Comment: @RobertdeJonge You mean like in S5 1416 and 2698 as values and then your S4 you have CODE and DEFINITION. So, you want it part of the whole sentence in S2 that we put in one string? or you want it separate? Because if just one then you could test for S4 and S5 as well.

Comment: Between those 2, one sentence, no multiple parts, which is what I am after :P

Comment: @RobertdeJonge I think you need to edit your post and provide examples on the possible output that you want. Honestly what you are asking although vague as of the moment is doable I presume. Hope I am not wrong though.